# Sitecore Deployment - Automatic deployment of Installed Layouts/XSLT from CM to CD

Tags: sitecore, environment, sitecore7

We're currently in the process of setting up a Scaled Sitecore 7.0 environment which has a single (Content Management) CM server and two load balanced (Content Delivery) CD servers.    I ran my install package on the CM server which included some custom Layouts (aspx) and custom Renderings (xslt).    I noticed those didn't persist from the CM to the CDs and I was wondering what the best practice would be to accomplish this without custom software. (Team Development for Sitecore (TDS))

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Sitecore Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to chapter 3.4 of the [Sitecore 7 Scaling Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf) which will suggest you to use [Microsoft Distributed File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) (as Jens pointed out) or the [Web Deployment Tool](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

I have implemented the Web Deploy solution a few times and that works pretty good, but it can be quite difficult to setup.
The DFS solution wasn't part of the Scaling Guide the last time I had to implement file synchronisation, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but in that section it says Sitecore does not support using DFS or Web Deploy to Syncronize files outside of /App_Data/MediaFiles  and /App_Config/Security.   Any idea why that is?

Comment: It's not supported, but it will probably work. We have used it for publication of binaries, configuration and sublayouts. Although the last time I used it was with Sitecore 6.5..

Answer (score 1):

I think most people not using TDS (which is by far worth its money), copies files manually. This is the most simpel and easy way. If you use the Sitecore packager for items and Visual Studio Web deploy for files (deploying to a local folder and the copy that across), you can install the items on your CM server and install the files to all servers.

You could also create a setup of some sort with [Microsoft DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29), but that would probably take a long time and I haven't seen a solution, where it works well.

Comment: I looked into DFS and setting up Web Deploy.   Both seemed pretty time intensive at this point so I settled with a robocopy script.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to deploy files, running a Powershell or Robocopy script is probably enough for you to push files out from one server to multiple targets.

In our automated deployments with TeamCity or TFS, we often use TDS but only for the items. We then use a Powershell step running Robocopy scripts to deploy build files out to multiple instances.